# Transfer Image (*.jpeg, *.png etc) file from client to server

Tags: java, sockets, file-upload, file-io

In my java application I want to transfer some Images from client to server.
I am using Socket to connect client with server.
It is working when I transfer string from client to server but I am not able to transfer Image file.

I am using

**BufferedInputStream**
**BufferedOutputStream**

for transferring string.

I know for transferring file I need to use FileInputStream as:

```
BufferedInputStream bis bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("111.JPG"));
```

But I don't know, what exactly I need to write.
so please give your answer by some sample of code.

Comment: You say you've got it working for Strings but not for image files.  In what way is it not working for images files?  If you're more specific about your problem people can be more specific about their answers.

Comment: *"please give your answer by some sample of code."*  Please insert cash.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should convert image to byte.
You can use this function.

```
static byte[] ImageToByte(System.Drawing.Image iImage)
{
MemoryStream mMemoryStream = new MemoryStream();
iImage.Save(mMemoryStream,
System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
return mMemoryStream.ToArray();
}
```

And you can call this function in your server program.

```
Bitmap tImage = new Bitmap(Image URL goes here);
byte[] bStream = ImageToByte(tImage);

while (true)
{
TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
Console.WriteLine("Connected");
while (client.Connected)
{
NetworkStream nStream = client.GetStream();
nStream.Write(bStream, 0,
bStream.Length);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many examples on the internet already:

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165006/simple-java-client-server-program)

[here](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/31995)

etc.

Please consider using google next time.

Comment: this is not exactly what he asked for (he already knows basic Java I/O)

Comment: @GavinCattell ya i know lot of site is there, that's why I am confused so please if you know some good site which mention all these thing then give the link here.

Comment: I not want basic client/server socket programming. I want to transfer image file from client to server.

Comment: You have both parts you need then. You take the bytes which you already have from your question and feed them over the connection.