# Java and android socket server programming

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sockets

I am planning to create an android application that will communicate into a pc server. does java socket programming works with different internet to android mobile device? example is my android mobile device is using gprs while my pc server is connected to dsl/modem

Comment: Probably not, because your pc is probably on private network. You could do it if they both were on same network, ie. wifi.

Comment: If only you could downvote comments. Hint: there's only one internet.

Comment: why, is something wrong with my comment?

Comment: Dude i tried doing it and my pc was on one (private network) and phone on wifi network on same provider. It did not work until they were both on same network, because routers block connections to private IP addresses. Learn stuff before you post some nonsense. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network

Comment: @DjDexter5GHz Google "port forwarding" and get back to us on that. The router doesn't "block" connections to private IPs, there's no *route* to them. Your router is translating using [Network Address Translation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation). Setting up port forwarding from your public IP to a machine on the private network is home networking 101

Comment: Nope, provider usually blocks everything. That's something (usually) only for provider use, since they paid a lot for those IP addresses, they will not let you bring up the server and use it for fun. (while paying only internet connection) There is sometimes possibility to do what you are talking about, but usually not.

Comment: lol ... erm, not so much. But hey ... you keep hold of that thinking you're right thing.

Comment: @Brian have you tried this doing yourself, and have you succeeded with port forwarding?

Comment: Only for the last 15 years or so. Why do you think some games and things like bittorrent have you forward ports? There's an entire small industry of dynamic DNS providers to allow you to map a domain name to your home IP address.

Comment: I am able to get my PC to work as a server and my phone as the client using USB-connect.  When using my broadband WIFI router, I need to set the router to send unsolicited traffic to my PC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they do work and there are many applications that are built on such a set-up. Try out simple client-server examples. Concentrate on creating the server first. You have to make sure that the firewall that your PC server is on, allows the server to accept connections and also that the IP address that you are connecting to is not a local IP. Check out the articles [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html), [here](http://systembash.com/content/a-simple-java-tcp-server-and-tcp-client/) [etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165006/simple-java-client-server-program)

Comment: sir how about if their distance is like 40 meters ? does it still works ? thankyou for your reply! :)

Comment: I am talking about the client and server being on the internet. So, distance does not matter at all. If you want it to be accessible over a local area network only, then, both have to be on the same network.

Comment: thankyou verymuch sir! now i have some ideas about socket :) *cheers*

Comment: Glad to help. Accept the answer if it did answer your question.